# Visualize estimated and true turtlebot position in rviz

Tags: gazebo, rviz, turtlebot, gazebo-simulator, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to illustrate the displacement of the correct and estimated position in rviz. Hence, I started the turtlebot simulation runing in Gazebo with a small office environement. A map of the enviroment is avialble on the map server.

Now I am not able to visualize the correct position in the map. Does a topic exist that provides the correct robot position in a Gazebo model?

Best wishes

Poseidonius

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43678/visualize-estimated-and-true-turtlebot-position-in-rviz/) by [Poseidonius](https://answers.ros.org/users/248/poseidonius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 427 on 2012-09-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For getting the estimated pose you will have to run amcl that uses the simulated laser and the map to localize itself. Unfortunately, for the turtlebot there is no ground truth pose topic as for the pr2. I guess you will have to subscribe to gazebo's model_state topic and translate the pose of the turtlebot to a PoseStamped or Odometry message. In python such a node should be just a few lines of code though.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0